# Question on generating power series for a function

Tags: power-series

When generating power series for the function $y = 1/(2-x)$
I can see two different ways of solving this question, but with very different answers.

1. SOLUTION: $$y=\frac{1}{1-(x-1)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty(x-1)^n$$
2. (official textbook) SOLUTION: $$ y= \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{1- \frac{x}{2}})=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2^n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{2^{n+1}}$$

two completely different answers for (what seems to me) very viable solutions! Please help! I Don't understand why!

I am sorry that I cannot format this properly.

Comment: sorry fixed it, still learning formatting

Comment: That's a good spirit ... I'll delete the unnecessary comments then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution 1 xpands the Function $y = \dfrac {1}{2-x}$ about $x=1$. whereas the second solution expands $y = \dfrac {1}{2-x}$ about $x=0$.

Comment: Does this depend entirely on the r term in the infinite geometric series sum a/(1-r)? Say if r = (x^2-2). Then this power series would be centred at 2?

Comment: but then the function would be different too

Comment: @ketan, nice solution...+1. Anyways sorry for what happened on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702772/evaluate-an-integral

Comment: @Apurv lets forget the past

Answer (score 0):

The binomial series expansion that you used -

$$
\frac1{1-y}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} y^n
$$

is valid only when $|y|<1$.  Otherwise, the series diverges.  In your solution, you are substituting in $(x-1)$ for $y$, so your solution is valid for $|x-1|<1$, so your power series is in some sense centred at $1$.  Indeed, your power series is not a power series in $x$, but a power series in $x-1$.  Normally, we want to find a series in $x$ (centred at $0$), and this is what the textbook solution is doing.  If we substitute in $\frac{x}{2}$ for $y$, then we get a series valid for $|x/2|<1$, or for $|x|<2$.

Note, however, that you can transform from one series to the other.  The following is non-rigorous, but can be tidied up if you want to:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (x-1)^n &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^k(-1)^{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k \sum_{n=k}^\infty {n\choose k} (-1)^{n-k}
\end{align}

At this point, the series $\sum_{n=k}^\infty {n\choose k} (-1)^{n-k}$ doesn't actually converge, but if you extend the notion of summation in a special way (called 'Abel summation', I think) then you can get it to come out as $2^{-n-1}$.  Not at all rigorous: has anyone got a better way of doing this?

Comment: I"m also hanging at this point, would be fine if someone knows how to solve that.